# ¿Como instalar Paquetes de Atom Manualmente?

Tags: php, css, html5, ajax

es decir, sin necesidad de irse a File > Settings > Install sino mas bien ir C:\Users\nombre_usuario.atom\packages y descomprimir e instalar ahi el archivo que descargue manualmente, de antemano gracias!

Comment: atom trae una utilidad para el manejo de los paquetes ver https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/atom-packages/#command-line

Answer (score 3):

Puedes instalar paquetes de/para **atom** si consigues descargarlos desde otro lugar y dejándolos en la carpeta "*packages*" que se encuentra en la carpeta "*.atom*"

[image: Ruta para la carpeta packages]

Es una ruta parecida a esta:

C:\Users\"*AquíVaElNombreDeTuUsuario*"\.atom\packages

En donde dice "*AquíVaElNombreDeTuUsuario*" en realidad varia según el nombre de tu usuario.

Por ejemplo, si quieres instalar el paquete "*script*" que te permite correr el código desde el mismo **atom**

[image: Ejemplo de paquete]

Puedes descargarlo desde la pagina de GitHub de ese usuario (suelen dejar información extra dentro del mismo post en **atom**) y solo descomprimir el .zip en la carpeta "*packages*" y listo. Suerte!

[image: Explicación de ruta 2]

PD: Estoy empezando e intentando aprender esto de la programación y lo acabo de hacer, lo siento si no expliqué bien.